# Why is my code outputting the original string value and the converted string value rather than just the converted string value?

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

```
string userInput = stringInput.Text;
string userSentence = userInput.ToLower();

foreach (char letter in userSentence)
{
    var sentence = morseCodeTable.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == letter.ToString()).Value ?? " / ";
    userSentence += sentence;
}

stringInput.Text = userSentence;
```

[image: output]

Comment: Because you initialize `userSentence` to the user's input, and then keep appending the morse code to that. You probably want `string userInput = stringInput.ToLower();` and `string userSentence = ""`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
   userSentence += sentence;
```

You are appending each char `sentence` that has been encrypted to the `userSentence`.

Then you return `userSentence` to the form.

Perhaps this will do

```
string userInput = stringInput.Text;
string userSentence = userInput.ToLower();
string encryptedSentence = "";

foreach (char letter in userSentence)
{
    var morseChar = morseCodeTable.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == letter.ToString()).Value ?? " / ";
    encryptedSentence += morseChar;
}

stringInput.Text = encryptedSentence;
```